# Apache not sending headers to PHP over FCGI/PHP-FPM

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, fcgi

I have a virtual host configured to process PHP files over Proxy:FCGI, and it works fine, except that PHP is not receiving custom headers and others, like "Origin".

Here my Apache 2.4 virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/my/host/directory/public"

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    ErrorLog "/my/host/directory/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "my/host/directory/logs/access.log" common

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV local
    Header always set Example01 "*"
    
    <Directory "my/host/directory/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Files ~ "\.php$">
        ProxyFCGIBackendType GENERIC
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000#"
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

and here, the PHP $_SERVER values returned:

```
Array
(
    [USER] => nobody
    [HOME] => /var/empty
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 55684
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /my/host/directory/public/index.php
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => you@example.com
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /my/host/directory/public
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /my/host/directory/public
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [SERVER_NAME] => domain.localhost
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.51 (Unix)
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH] => /usr/local/apache-2.4.51/lib
    [PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-us
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.1 Safari/605.1.15
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_HOST] => domain.localhost
    [proxy-nokeepalive] => 1
    [APPLICATION_ENV] => local
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1636663645.6605
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1636663645
)
```

I was expecting a header named "Example01" and others, but nothing. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The instruction "CGIPassAuth On" solved my problem. My config changed from

```
    <Files ~ "\.php$">
        ProxyFCGIBackendType FPM
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9002#"
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

to

```
    <Files ~ "\.php$">
        CGIPassAuth On
        ProxyFCGIBackendType FPM
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9002#"
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```